# Having trouble passing NNString label name from MasterView to DetailView

Tags: ios, xcode, master-detail

I'm trying to make a Master-Detail app that displays a list of Sounds on the master view. When you tap the sound, you go to the detail screen, and it displays the Sound you chose as a label, then shows a short movie of the sound. My problem is, all the sounds show as the label the name of the first sound in the list.  When I tap on Sound B, the detail screen shows "Sound B."  When I tap on tSound F, the detail screen shows "Sound B."

No errors or warnings come up. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

slfViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface slfViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

@end
```

slfViewController.m

```
#import "slfViewController.h"
#import "slfSoundDetailViewController.h"

@interface slfViewController ()

@end

@implementation slfViewController 
{
    NSArray *tableData;
    NSArray *thumbnails;
}

@synthesize tableView = _tableView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    tableData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
             @"B Sound", 
             @"Ch Sound", 
             @"D Sound", 
             @"F Sound", 
                ...
             @"Zh Sound",
             nil];

thumbnails = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
              @"b.jpg", 
              @"ch.jpg", 
              @"d.jpg", 
              @"f.jpg", 
                ...
              @"zh.jpg",
              nil];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showSoundDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        slfSoundDetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.soundName = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
}

#pragma mark - TableView Data Source methods

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [tableData count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"soundCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[thumbnails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}


@end
```

slfSoundDetailViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface slfSoundDetailViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *soundLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *soundName;

@end
```

slfSoundDetailViewController.m

```
#import "slfSoundDetailViewController.h"

@interface slfSoundDetailViewController ()

@end

@implementation slfSoundDetailViewController

@synthesize soundLabel;
@synthesize soundName;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    soundLabel.text = soundName;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You’re only setting `soundLabel.text = soundName` in `viewDidLoad`… so it’s only being called once (when the view controller’s view is first loaded). This app is most likely reusing the same instance of `slfSoundDetailViewController` so it doesn’t reload its view.

You’ll probably want to override either `-[slfSoundDetailViewController setSoundName:]` or `-[slfSoundDetailViewController viewWillAppea:]` and set `soundLabel.text` there.